# Can someone explain the CSS and Markup to make a table like GMail's mail view?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying make a table act like the one GMail uses to show the inbox contents:

[image: GMail Inbox Table]

Namely the behaviour I want to replicate is the right hand Date column - it slides over the top of the middle column which contains the subject line and beginnings of message. The right hand column is also of a fixed width.

The left hand columns are also fixed width and always show the email senders name, no matter how much you compress the view.

I've been trying for a while but I feel this might use some CSS Table magic that I'm not familiar with. I'm looking to understand the how and why of implementing this, not just to mindlessly copy the code from GMail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key here is using `table-layout:fixed;` on the parent table element and

```
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
```

on the cell that you would like to be flexible. I have produced a working example (resize the panels to see it in action)

http://jsfiddle.net/JNGyL/1/

Comment: The borders in the css are not necessary, they are used for illustrative purposes only.

Comment: table-layout: fixed is what I was missing in my understanding - thank you for being so helpful.

Comment: Also worth adding width: 300%; to the p tag so that it stays on one line.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not really tabular data that you are displaying, you might prefer to try a div-based approach, something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
.outer {
  display: table; 
  table-layout: fixed; 
  width: 100%;
}

.outer div {
  display: table-cell; 
  padding: 5px;
}

.outer :first-child, .outer :last-child {
  width: 100px; 
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.outer :last-child {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.middle {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="outer">
  <div>First cell</div> 
  <div class="middle">Second cell second cell second cell second cell second cell second cell second cell second cell second cell second cell second cell second cell second cell </div> 
  <div>Third cell</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully that's simple enough not to require much explanation, but one of the keys is `table-layout: fixed;`